# I am having problems with my script. Is there a way to fix this?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When I exited my script, there was a compilation error "Assets\Scripts\PointAndShoot.cs(47,41): error CS1002: ; expected", I looked everywhere, but I can't find the error, pls help me.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PointAndShoot : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float number;
    private Vector3 target;
    public GameObject crosshairs;
    public GameObject gun;
    public GameObject[] projectiles;
    public GameObject bulletStart;

    public float bulletSpeed;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Cursor.visible = false;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        //set target to mouse position.
        target = transform.GetComponent<Camera>().ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, transform.position.z));

        //set crosshairs to mouse position.
        crosshairs.transform.position = new Vector2(target.x, target.y);
        
        //rotate gun to mouse position.
        Vector3 difference = target - gun.transform.position;
        float rotationZ = Mathf.Atan2(difference.y, difference.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg - 90f;
        gun.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0.0f, 0.0f, rotationZ);

        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            float distance = difference.magnitude;
            Vector2 direction = difference / distance;
            direction.Normalize();
            fireBullet(direction, rotationZ);
        }
    }

    void fireBullet(Vector2 direction, float rotationZ){
        projectiles[FindTheProjectile()].transform.position = bulletStart.transform.position;
        projectiles[FindTheProjectile()]GetComponent<ProjectileScript>().Activate();
        projectiles[FindTheProjectile()].transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0.0f, 0.0f, rotationZ);
        projectiles[FindTheProjectile()].GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = direction * bulletSpeed;
    }

    private int FindTheProjectile()
    {
       for(int i = 0; i < projectiles.Length; i++)
       {
          if(!projectiles[i].activeInHierarchy)
             {
                return i;
             }
       }
       return 0;
    }

}
```

Thank you for your kind attention.

When I clicked on the error the line where the error is did not pop up, by the way.

Comment: `PointAndShoot.cs(47,41)` means the file PointAndShoot, line 47 and the 41 char on that line. So check line 47 and (probably) the end of that line for a missing semicolon.

Comment: Here: `projectiles[FindTheProjectile()]GetComponent<ProjectileScript>().Activate();` there is a missing dot before GetComponent. Should be: `projectiles[FindTheProjectile()].GetComponent<ProjectileScript>().Activate();`

Comment: As a genera recommendation: Instead of `GameObject` have a proper root component (e.g. for instance your `ProjectileScript`) which holds references to all the other components you need to access later on like here `Rigidbody2D` .. and also cache the result of `FindTheProjectile()` .. currently you are doing the work 4 times ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In line

```
projectiles[FindTheProjectile()]GetComponent<ProjectileScript>().Activate();
```

You're missing `.` before `GetComponent`
:D

Comment: [Should you answer questions where the cause of the problem is a typo?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366135/should-you-answer-questions-where-the-cause-of-the-problem-is-a-typo)